# Will a Russian citizen with US green card traveling through Stockholm need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, sweden, russian-citizens, arn

I recently flew from LAX to Pulkovo with a layover in Stockholm Arlanda and was not able to go to my connecting flight without going through passport control. I was initially told I cannot enter the airport without a Schengen visa, but accidentally ended up in the Schengen zone when an airport employee mistakenly bypassed passport control and took me there by elevator.  Luckily, I was able to return airside without a visa.

I'm returning to the US next weekend and was told by my traveling companion (who recently flew back) that she had to go through passport control and re-enter the security checkpoint even though she was connecting to a non-Schengen destination.  She's a US citizen.

Am I correct in my understanding that my US green card will allow me to go through passport control without a Schengen visa? I'm a Russian citizen.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get to my connecting flight airside without going through passport control. My connecting gate was not listed on my ticket and I didn't see a connecting gate on my companion's ticket either.

EDIT:

Arriving flight from LED is in Terminal 5. Departing flight to LAX is also in Terminal 5. Both flights are from gates within F58-F69.

Comment: This question is a bit hard to interpret because "transit zone" would normally mean the _international_ side of the Schengen passport control lines -- and as a Russian citizen you can certainly transit _there_ without a visa. Should we understand "transit zone" in your question as the area _airside_ of security but _landside_ of immigration (from which intra-Schengen flights depart)?

Comment: ARN does have a door to enable those doing non-Schengen to non-Schengen to bypass passport control and go back airside. But it isn't opened unless you press an intercom and ask someone to come and open it (very few people are doing this kind of transit and most can glide through passport control twice). Otherwise you will be directed to passport control. That may be the source of confusion.

Comment: I'm connecting from non-Schengen country to a non-Schengen country. How do I get to my connecting gate in the same terminal?

Comment: @Calchas If arriving at T5F and needing to Change to T5B or T2, you'll press a button at a door right next to Immigration, whereby a bus will arrive, and security staff will eventually come out and check you+luggage. Sometimes security staff take a good while to Show up, in which case the bus will stand waiting, as the door cannot be opened until security's cleared

Answer (score 3):

Check out Stockholm Arlanda's [airport map](https://www.swedavia.com/arlanda/find-at-the-airport/?_ga=1.109624962.6636722.1488183492) and then check from which terminal airlines operating your flights fly, to see if you need to change terminal and go through the passport control.

Just a reminder: you will need a Schengen visa to go through the passport control. Your residency status in the US is of no importance here.

Comment: The map doesn't make it clear that you have to ring a door bell and wait for someone to open a special door for you to do this type of transit. :)